# SQL Server 2008 : Re-runnable stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to make my stored procedure re-runnable.

If it started and run partial way and failed because of a reason, it should be re-runnable.

Please suggest some ways to do that.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have transactions wrapped around your sql query in your stored proc? e.g. `commit` and `rollback`

Comment: The stored procedure that I'm gonna execute is just updating a couple of columns in a particular table. Do I still need TRY and CATCH ?

Comment: cctan : No there is no commit and rollback in sProc !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JOB and trigger it in the stored procedure. 
Specify the retry times and the retry interval on the Step (work) that you want to re-run.

here's a reference on how to start a Job.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1730/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-agent-job/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to execute your stored procedure from beginning after failure, you can catch the failrue (using [TRY .. CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or [@@ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)) and then redirect the execution to the begin of the stored procedure using [GOTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)